# How to sum a column in a matrix and paste the value in the last cell in r?

Tags: r

Is there a way to sum up all the values in from a column and paste them into the last "cell"?

Example: I have a matrix like:

```
  1  2  3
1 0  0  1
2 0  0  2
3 0  0  6
```

and I want (need) a Matrix like:

```
  1  2  3
1 0  0  0
2 0  0  0
3 0  0  9
```

In addition to that I need an iterative Approach, because my matrix dimensions vary.

Thank you in advance!

edit:

the following solution worked:

```
creating a second zero'd matrix with the same dimensions and the following code 
matrix2[nrow(matrix2),] <- colSums(m1)
```

Comment: You can do `m1[nrow(m1), ] <- colSums(m1)`

Comment: using `colSums` is giving me the following Error : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions. My matrix was built due sum(if_else(condition....)).

Comment: I was assuming that you have a `matrix` as shown above.  Please check the data in my post.  It is a matrix.  Can you check the `str(yourmatrix)`

Comment: str(matrix) gives me `num [1:3, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4.5 4`

Comment: that looks good.  Not clear why you got the error because it is working fine for me.   assume that you had the `,` as in the comments

Comment: okay it is working if I define a new matrix `matrix2[nrow(matrix2),] <- colSums(m1)`

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is.  Is it always the last column? Is the matrix to be zero'd first?

Comment: may be it is some version issue?

Comment: i created a new matrix2 with identical proportions. But now the other rows are `NA`. edit: okay how to get rid of the `NA's` was in your solution G. Grothendieck! thanks for that

Comment: I have added a response to the NA question  to my answer but please also answer the question I asked above.

Comment: its doing colsums on every column and i created a zero'd matrix before or what was your question?

Comment: Please edit the question so that it is self contained.

Answer (score 2):

We provide several solutions depending on the interpretation of the question.  They all assume that a zero matrix is to be returned except for the last row. (1) sums just the last column, (2) sums column(s) i and (2a) sums all columns.

All solutions are one line except for defining nr and/or nc and preserve the original m matrix returning the new matrix.

**1)** Using `m` shown reproducibly in the note at the end multiply m by zero and then replace the last cell (which would be at position `prod(dim(m))`, with the sum of the last column.

```
nc <- ncol(m)
replace(0 * is.na(m), prod(dim(m)), sum(m[, nc]))
##   1 2 3
## 1 0 0 0
## 2 0 0 0
## 3 0 0 9
```

If `m` is known not have NAs then is.na(m) can be replaced with m in the above code.

**2)** If the column is not necessarily last then if i is the index of the column to sum (or it can be a vector of the indexes of those columns to be summed should there be more than one) then:

```
i <- 3
nr <- nrow(m)
replace(0 * is.na(m), i * nr, colSums(m[, i, drop = FALSE]))
```

**2a)** If all columns are to be summed then i <- 1:nc so the above becomes:

```
nc <- ncol(m)
nr <- nrow(m)
replace(0 * is.na(m), (1:nc) * nr, colSums(m, na.rm = TRUE))
```

If you need to be able to handle matrices with zero columns then use `seq_len(nc)` instead of `1:nc`.

### Note

```
m <- matrix(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L), 3, dimnames = list(1:3, 1:3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your matrix is given by

```r
mat <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,6,0,0,7), nrow=4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Then

```r
mat_2 <- matrix(0L, nrow=dim(mat)[1], ncol=dim(mat)[2])
```

gives you matrix with same dimensions and containing just `0s`. Now calculate the sum by

```r
mat_2[dim(mat)[1],] <- apply(mat, 2, sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `colSums`

```
m1[nrow(m1),] <- colSums(m1, na.rm = TRUE)
m1[-nrow(m1),] <- 0
m1
#  1 2 3
#1 0 0 0
#2 0 0 0
#3 0 0 9
```

---

Or with `addmargins`

```
addmargins(m1, 1)[-1,] * rep(0:1, c(nrow(m1)- 1, 1))
```

#### data

```
m1 <-  matrix(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L), 3, dimnames = list(1:3, 1:3))
```

Comment: I was wondering about the difference between `colSums` (and similar functions) and `apply` with `fun=sum`. `?colSums`revealed: `These functions are equivalent to use of apply with FUN = mean or FUN = sum with appropriate margins, but are a lot faster. `

Comment: @MartinGal `apply` is similar to a `for` loop and should be the same efficiency as of a for loop but it is  convenient with less side effects (but sometimes sideeffects are needed).  `colSums` or `rowSums` are vectorized versions which makes it faster